# how do I properly pass results from jQuery $.ajax() through several functions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'd like to pass the result of my ajax function to another one (sort of like "bubbling up an event"). I *really* need to keep the ajax wrapper function as-is, i.e. generic, so I'm looking for a solution that does not touch `myAjaxHandler()`

```
$('button').on(
    'click', 
    myAjaxHandler()
);


function myAjaxHandler(){
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}

myAjaxHandler().done(
    function(result){
        console.log(result); // shows 'hello'
    }
).then(
    console.log('hi') // shows before 'hello'
);
```

I first get 'hi', then 'hello', but i want it the other way: first 'hello', then 'hi'. I'm sure I'm not using `.then()` in the correct way and frankly I'm beginning to think that I will never really grasp `$.Deferreds` - and I assume `$.ajax` is a `Deferred` object with all its benefits and idiosyncrasies...

Comment: Your `then` callback isn't a function.

Comment: +1 for being the solution - too bad i can't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you. It doesn't mess with the `myAjaxHandler()`

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

    myAjaxHandler().done(function(results){
        console.log(results); //Say Hello
        sayHiFunction();      //Say Hi
    });

});


function myAjaxHandler(){
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}

function sayHiFunction(){
    console.log('hi');
}
```

Comment: the sayHiFunction() will complete beofre the ajaxHandler() is done.

Comment: @tim ? I'm not calling the `sayHiFunction();` until `ajaxHandler()` is done. I'm not sure what's wrong. I just tested it myself and it worked fine.